# LZString python installed on raspberry pi is very slow

Tags: javascript, python, compression

I have been testing different compression on python on a pi and while zlib is fast it doesn't seem to match up the compression when the data gets to javascript and so I tried LZString.

LZString works perfectly. I am able to send the compressed data through simplewebsock with this code:

```
        x = lzstring.LZString()
        elogger.debug('Start Compression')
        respz = x.compressToUTF16(self.data)
        elogger.debug('End Compression')
        for client in clients:
            if client != self:
                client.sendMessage(respz)
```

Which is great.

The problem is that it takes over 6 seconds to do the compression on the 300k characters I am sending. Another oddity is that when I install LZString from the git repository as opposed to pips, it runs in under a second but the data is not readable after the websocket transmits it to my javascript in the browser.

So in summary:

Zlib runs quickly but the data does not seem to be compressed in the same format required by zlib in javascript (using pako or zlib)

LZScript installed via pip works to send the data but it takes 6 seconds to compress. It does a good job compressing as well.

LZScript installed from github repository runs very quickly but the data is not readable by LZScript in javascript.

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: I've never even heard of lzstring before, but for zlib keep in mind that zlib contains three similar "formats": deflate, zlib, and gzip.  Make sure you're using the same one on both sides.

Comment: That in itself is very helpful. I understand that deflate relates to inflate... What does zlib uncompress with?

Comment: Deflate/inflate is the only one with a different name.  zlib decompresses with zlib, gzip decompresses with gzip.